# Bootstrap-select v1.14.0-beta3 still not working with Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-select

I know this has been asked elsewhere but this is in regards to the very latest version of [Bootstrap-select](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select).

The README.MD states the component now has support for Bootstrap 5. But code that worked perfectly in Bootstrap 4 but was broken with Bootstrap 5 looks no different after upgrading to 1.14.0.

It functions okay. But it doesn't look right.

[image]

Again, this worked perfectly with version v1.13.14 and Bootstrap 4.

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="control-label" for="User_Roles">Roles</label>
        <select class="form-select selectpicker" multiple id="User_Roles" name="User.Roles">
            <option value="Staff">Staff</option>
            <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
            <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
        </select>
        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="User.Roles" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, except for me the dropdown won't even open. Aside from reverting back to bootstrap 4, were you able to figure out a workaround for this?

Comment: @Larisa: The issue is that bootstrap-select doesn't support Bootstrap 5. Someone posted some fixes on their GitHub account and I was able to get those working.